# How can I set an instance variable dynamically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pyobjc

I can set a instance variable via a @property using:

```
SEL s = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@:", property]);
[self performSelector: s withObject: newObject];
```

but is there a way  to set an instance variable directly and dynamically ?

Comment: Why do you want to? Private instance variables are meant to be private. What is your specific goal here?

Comment: I want to create UIImageViews based on an xml file which will be read at init, with coordinates and image name to load. But I forgot I can just use a Xib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite as efficient as using a selector directly, but you can use -[setValue:forKey:] to set properties dynamically. So, if you have a property named *foo* and you want to set it to *@"bar"*, you would do:

```
[self setValue:@"bar" forKey:@"foo"];
```

Just remember, since this only takes object references, you have to properly box any primitives. So, if you have a property called *foobar* that takes an *NSInteger* value, you would do:

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:5] forKey:@"foobar"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self setValue:newObject forKey:property];
```